# Take in a input using tkinter clicking a button and then returning whatever I typed in to be able to pass it into other functions

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm very new to the tkinter module and have little to no experience with it.
I want to make a program where I could run it and an entry box would display as well as a button.

What I want the program to do is, when I left click the button, the canvas would close, and I would be able to assign a variable to the entry I typed in and be able to pass that to other functions. So I'd have tkinter.Entry('Type in text'), then after that I would click the tkinter.Button('Click Me'), and once I click the button the canvas would close and then be able to assign the tkinter.Entry as a variable that I could pass through to other functions.

In my program I was able to just do regular python without the canvas and type in an input() and then return that to my other functions, but I'm completely lost on how to remove the input() from console and replace it with a UI canvas with tkinter. Sorry if this isn't making a lot of sense.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Code Violation")
def Canvas():
    keyword = tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Keyword").grid(row=0)
    tester = tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate File").grid(columnspan=2)
    tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row=0, column=1)
    window.mainloop()
```

----Afterwards Error Codes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oalbz/PycharmProjects/Code_Violation/CodeViolation.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/oalbz/PycharmProjects/Code_Violation/CodeViolation.py", line 29, in main
    keyword = Canvas()
  File "C:/Users/oalbz/PycharmProjects/Code_Violation/CodeViolation.py", line 12, in Canvas
    Var = tkinter.StringVar()
  File "C:\Users\oalbz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 480, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\oalbz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

---

I want to be able to take the entry.get() that's insie the callback function and return it to my main and use that as a parameter in my vacancy function
here is the code for my main

```
def main():
    #Canvas()
    keyword = Canvas()
    print(keyword)
    initial_index = open('CodeViolationIndex.html','r')
    table_dict = removeTags(initial_index,'tr','td')
    site_final_html = open('test.html','w')
    #keyword = input('Enter Keyword you would like to search:')
    vacancy(table_dict,keyword)
```

---

This is what I have so far in my Canvas function you gave me

```
def Canvas():
    Var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Keyword").grid(row=0)
    entry = tkinter.Entry(window, text="Enter Keyword",textvariable = Var)
    entry.grid(row=1)
    def callback():
        keyword = entry.get()
        #print(keyword)
        window.destroy()
        return keyword


    tester = tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate File",command=callback)
    tester.grid(columnspan=2)
    keyword = callback()
    return keyword
```

Comment: I created a function where I had a label say Say Enter Keyword and a Entry and I have a button but when I type anything in or click the button nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Code Violation")
def Canvas():
    Var = tkinter.StringVar()   #Making a variable which will store data
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Keyword:").grid(row=0)   #Making label, no need to store it in a variable
    entry = tkinter.Entry(window, text="Enter Keyword", textvariable = Var) #making entry
    entry.grid(row=1)
    def callback(): #this function will be triggered on button press
        print(entry.get())   #get() method will give the value of the entry 
        window.destroy()     #It will destroy the tkinter window
    tester = tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate File", command = callback)
    tester.grid(columnspan=2)
Canvas()
window.mainloop()
```

#### Edit:

Here is the code updated according to your updates:

```
import tkinter

def Canvas():
    global keyword
    window = tkinter.Tk()
    window.title("Code Violation")
    Var = tkinter.StringVar()
    tkinter.Label(window, text="Enter Keyword").grid(row=0)
    entry = tkinter.Entry(window, text="Enter Keyword",textvariable = Var)
    entry.grid(row=1)
    def callback():
        global keyword
        keyword = entry.get()
        window.destroy() #This also quits the mainloop so function will continue to return statement

    tester = tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate File",command=callback)
    #               >>>>            >>>>             >>>>       ^ We are assigning the function callback here
    tester.grid(columnspan=2)
    window.mainloop()
    return keyword

def main():
    #Canvas()
    keyword = Canvas()
    print(keyword)
    #...

main()
```

Comment: thank you I was able to take in my Entry and I got it into the console, but I get a bunch of error messages ill attach it to the post Im also trying to pass through the entry.get() back to my main function and then once I have it in main I can pass it through to my other functions

Comment: Looks like you are modifying the code. Can you share it with me?

Comment: @OmarAl-Bazergan I updated the code. And please don't add the code in the question that I gave you and you edited. You can use some online code snippets and share the link with me through comments. But not in the question.